# Linear Regression Hypothesis equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

(WARNING: I know no maths)
I was watching this machine learning tutorial and I saw this equation:

[image]

I dont understand how the point on the second graph is at 1.0, shouldn't it be at 0.5 and same for the third graph, shouldnt that be at 1.5?

If this is a stupid question please comment why before down-voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second graph, we have $h_\theta(x)=0.5x$. In order to make everything nice integers, they made $x=2$, so they got:
$$h_\theta(x)=0.5*2=1$$

Similarly, for the third graph, we have $h_\theta(x)=0.5x+1$. In order to make everything nice integers, they made $x=2$, so they got:
$$h_\theta(x)=0.5*2+1=2$$

Always remember to look at the value of $x$ (the independent variable) so you can understand the value of $h_\theta(x)$ (the dependent variable). This is very important whenever you are working with some sort of independent/dependent variables or functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer! It didnt say the value of x=2. I guess I was meant to figure that out by myself.